# Ordering from Canada, charged in CAD or USD?

Tags: united-states, canada, usd-us-dollar, cad-canadian-dollar

I am thinking about ordering something from a website based in Canada and I live in the U.S. I am just wondering if I order from them, will I be paying the listed price in CAD or USD? Will it convert and charge me USD in the end?

For example: The item is listed $100 on the Canadian website, will I pay $75 after it is converted to USD?

Comment: did you check the website?

Comment: the simple answer is yes, if it says "$" symbol on a Canadian company, they simply mean Canadian dollars.   One of the few exceptions I know of is Amazon - Japan.  If you are in say europe or US, and you buy from the *Japan* amazon site (people do that to purchase speciality videos etc), they have so much business like that, there's literally a thing at the end that allows you to choose which currency you want to pay in.  (Unless they've changed it recently.)  But that's only because Amazon is huge.  Sure, the simple answer to your question is "Canadian".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, businesses always charge their 'home' currency, so if the shop is in Canada, you will pay Canadian Dollars. Normally you don't have any choices either.

Your credit card company will convert it to your currency, using the current international currency exchange rate (pretty good), plus a potential fee between 0 and 5% - depending on your credit card (not so good).

If it is a significant amount, or you plan to do that more than once, and if you have multiple credit cards, check first to see which one has the lowest international fee; 0% is not uncommon, but neither is 3 or 4%. If it's a 10$ thingy, it's probably not worth the time; but 4% of 1000 is already 40$...

As of right now, the currency exchange rate is 1.33, so you would pay ~75 USD; plus the potential fee, 0$ - 4$. Understand that this exchange rate is floating continuously; it probably won't change much, but it will change.